# How to figure out this impossible bug?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Unfortunately I can't provide reduce code sample because bug happens after main game update loop has ran like 11+ times, but I hope project is simple enough.

This is link to project:
https://github.com/marko-avlijas/udacity-frogger

Project is udacity game project and it comes with 3 files, but I have modified only `app.js` so that's where the bug must be.

Problem starts in `engine.js` in function `UpdateEntities` which I haven't changed.

```
function updateEntities(dt) {
    allEnemies.forEach(function(enemy) {
       // this is the line which calls problem function
        enemy.update(dt);
    });
    player.update();
}
```

Which then calls this in `app.js`:

```
Enemy.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    // this is the line which is causing error
    this.area.updateOuterLeft(this.area.outer.left + dt*this.speed);
    if (this.area.outer.left > settings.canvas.width)
        this.area.updateOuterLeft = -settings.canvas.width*2.5;
};
```

Somehow this works fine first 11? times that `updateEntities()` is run, but after that I get this error

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.area.updateOuterLeft is not a function
at Enemy.update (file:///data/komp_tuts/udacity/oo_js/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game-master/js/app.js:123:15)
at file:///data/komp_tuts/udacity/oo_js/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game-master/js/engine.js:100:19
at Array.forEach (native)
at updateEntities (file:///data/komp_tuts/udacity/oo_js/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game-master/js/engine.js:99:20)
at update (file:///data/komp_tuts/udacity/oo_js/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game-master/js/engine.js:83:9)
at main (file:///data/komp_tuts/udacity/oo_js/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game-master/js/engine.js:49:9)
```

In debuggger I see that `this` is set to `window`, not `enemy` like it should have been.
`window` doesn't have `area` defined so I get that error.

I can't figure this out. Please help.

Tips on how to debug this are also welcome.

I have set a counter to see how many times it `updateEntities()` gets called and it's 11 when I get the error. But when I put if statement to console.log on 11 time, error happens 13th time. When I put a stop at 13th time, there is no error and it happens a bit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `.update` function, where you replaced existing function with  `this.area.updateOuterLeft = -settings.canvas.width*2.5;`

Now `.updateOuterLeft` turned into floating value rather than function.

```
Enemy.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    // this is the line which is causing error
    this.area.updateOuterLeft(this.area.outer.left + dt*this.speed);
    if (this.area.outer.left > settings.canvas.width)
        this.area.updateOuterLeft = -settings.canvas.width*2.5;//<====
};
```

Comment: How did you figure it out so quickly? Just by looking at the code or some advanced chrome debugger kung fu?

Comment: It's like becoming detective in code where ur also a murderer..;)

I followed below steps
1) In your code you already `called` `.updateOuterLeft` function, and it breaks after sometime
2) This means someone is changing `.updateOuterLeft`.
3) Error itself saying `this.area.updateOuterLeft is not a function`.
4) Now start looking which line is the culprit